# ubuntu virtual console screws up colours in X11

Tags: ubuntu, colors, xorg

Whenever I use a virtual console on my machine, then return to the graphical environment, colours stop displaying correctly. At first I thought it was just displaying at a lower colour depth, but the problem seems to compound to the point where I'm having trouble reading any text in the graphical display.

The problem isn't permanent, restarting solves it, and it occasionally solves itself, but it's extremely frustrating. Any suggestions?

Cheers.

Comment: Log a bug in the video driver.